# rounding a decimal in C# based on user input

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to round decimals based on the user input instead of predefined values.

e.g. User inputs 1.2345, then they input the amount of decimals they need it rounded to like say 3. It would then round it and output 1.236

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to round decimals based on input, only predefined values.

What would be the best way to do something like this?

Comment: You can use [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @MaxXapi Hi, I have tried that one but it didn't output anything instead it just ends

Comment: @confusedperson - It would have been good to see what you had tried. We could have helped you correct the misconceptions you had rather than only just giving you an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity had only written Math.Round(value, input);
I hadn't tried the MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero method which was the missing piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Math.Round`

```
var input = 3;
var value = 1.2345;

var result = Math.Round(value, input, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: Hi, This answer helped me! I'll mark this as the answer once enough time has passed and I'm allowed to.